# Two password one login and one sudo but under the same account?

Tags: sudo, password

I have a laptop that has a really complicated password, however I don't want to keep typing this in during procedurs that requires sudo. Can I have another more simple sudo password after logging in for routine stuff? Is this a security risk? thanks.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94626/set-sudo-password-differently-from-login-one

Comment: Yes, you may have other password, and yes, simple password is a security risk.